# Llenar arrays con los valores de un array principal

Tags: php, array

Hola a todos me pueden ayudar con esto de PHP.
Tengo un array de N valores lo que quiero es poder pasar los valores del array principal en otro array de 3 termina de imprimir los valores debe abrirse otro array para meterlos valores e imprimir y así consecutivamente.

```
<?php 
$numeros=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

$numero=[$numeros];
for ($i=0; $i <count($numeros) ; $i++){ 
    if ($i<=2) {
      $numero= $numeros[$i];
      echo $i."--->".$numero."<br>";
    }
}
 ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

No puedo acomodar cuándo el array es N valores con tu ejemplo me puedes ayudar primera vez que estoy programando con lo que aprendí.

Comment: Has intentado algo? Publica lo que llevas para poder orientarte de mejor manera ;)

Comment: Puedes por favor plantear de forma más detallada lo que buscas lograr?

Answer (score 1):

- Tienes un vector con N cantidad de valores
- Debemos pasar determinada cantidad de valores del vector original a cada uno de los nuevos grupos
- Podemos iterar el vector original completo y por dentro mediante condicionales verificar cuando el **índice** tiene determinado valor para que de esa forma hagamos un `arra_push` a cada uno de los vectores vacíos con los valores recuperados hasta ese número de iteraciones del vector original
- Finalmente imprimimos por fuera del ciclo cada uno de los array recién llenados

Quedando el código de esta forma:

```
$numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

$grupoUno = [];
$grupoDos = [];
$grupoTres = [];

for($i = 0; $i<count($numeros); $i++) 
{
    if($i <= 3) {
        array_push($grupoUno, $numeros[$i]);
    } else if($i > 3 && $i <= 7) {
        array_push($grupoDos, $numeros[$i]);
    } else {
        array_push($grupoTres, $numeros[$i]);
    }
}

print_r($grupoUno);
print_r($grupoDos);
print_r($grupoTres);
```

Con una salida así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 8
)
Array
(
    [0] => 9
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 11
)
```

**Referencia**

- [Función **`array_push()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, podrías intentar con el siguiente código:

```
$numeros = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function fragmentar($arreglo, $filas) {

    $a_partes = array_chunk($arreglo, $filas);

    foreach($a_partes as $key => $group) {
        foreach($group as $key2 => $element) {
            echo $key2 . "--->" . $element."<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

fragmentar($numeros, 4);
```

Cabe señalar que hice uso de la función array_chunk para dividir el arreglo en subarreglos que contengan 4 elementos, como es el caso tuyo y luego recorrí el resultado con un doble foreach para imprimir la estructura que deseas.